# How to Sum through Vectors elements

Tags: matlab, for-loop, vector, indexing, sum

I have a variable quantity that contains two vectors. I want to sum these quantity from i = 1 to n, where n = 100. When the program is ran, I can click on the variables in the work space to see the element values of the vectors for each column position. When executing the variable of its position I get the corresponding value, (for e.g., z(1) = 73.2360, z(2) = 63.3701, .... and so on). But what I cannot seem to figure out is how to index thee vectors for the sum to run through the elements of the two vectors. For example in a for loop. I also took a look at `symsum()`, but that needed just generic variables. I am trying to sum epsilon from i = 1 to 100, where z_i and w_i are vectors of interest. I hope the MWE will show more of what I want to accomplish.

MWE:

```
 a = 0.6;
 b = sqrt(16-a^2);
 c = 6.5;
 d = sqrt(225-c^2);
 xh = randn(1,100);
 yw = randn(1,100);
  z = a*xh + b*yw + 68;
  w = c*xh + d*yw + 160;

     n = 100;                              % # of data entries.
  zbar = ((1/n)*sum(z));                   % Height data.
  wbar = ((1/n)*sum(w));                   % Weight data.
 Zbarv = zbar*ones(1,100);                 % Height data vector.
 Wbarv = wbar*ones(1,100);                 % Weight data vector.

sz = sqrt((1/n)*((z-Zbarv)*(transpose(z)-transpose(Zbarv))));              
sw = sqrt((1/n)*((w-Wbarv)*(transpose(w)-transpose(Wbarv)))); 

czw = ((1/n)*(w-Wbarv)*(transpose(z)-transpose(Zbarv)));
rzw = czw/(sz*sw);

 b = wbar - ((czw/sz^2)*zbar);             % y-intercept
 m = czw/sz^2;                             % Slope
 epsilon = (1/(n-1))*sum((w-(m*z+b)).^2);  % Error
```

The epsilon should be summing this, but should be a sum from `i=[1,100]`. I do not know how to index the values of the `w_i` and `z_i` vectors to for the sum to run through them. I tried making a input variable to them like `z(i)` and `w(i)`but turned out messy.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So you want to calculate the sum of the first i elements for every value of `i` between 1 and 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you just want:

```
epsilon = (1/(n-1))*sum((w(1:100)-(m*z(1:100)+b)).^2);
```

Although since you `w` and `z` are just 100 elements long, I think this is the same as what you've done. So I think your code is actually correct as it stands.

For example if `a = [1 2 3]`, then `sum(a)` is `6`, you don't actually have to index `a` to get the sum. So your code is finding the sum of all 100 elements.

You should read up on the [Matlab colon operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colon.html)

The basic idea is that in matlab something like `1:10` is just short hand for `[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]` and you can use that to index a vector. So if we have a vector `v = rand(100,1)` then to get the first 10 elements of `v` it's just `v(1:10)`

Comment: Don't think that's what the OP wants. `x` and `z` already have 100 samples, the colon indexing is superfluous.

Comment: @EitanT Yes I agree, I've said as much in the answer. I think the OPs code is correct tbh.

Comment: @Dan: I checked the code too, and I think you are right! But perhaps the OP is looking for kinda cumulative sum? Otherwise the question sounds quite cryptic to me.

Comment: @Dan: Thanks. I just came to a realization that the vectors are already indexed and when doing the sum, it will do the vector arithmetic operations automatically with just `sum`. I feel such a floosy, been thinking about how to do this for so long. I am just used to working in a different environment than matlab. Thank You for the response and verification it is done right `:)`